# Como mudar dados de um gráfico dinamicamente (DESLOC + NOME de RANGE)?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou tentando criar um gráfico dinâmico onde um combo muda o tipo de gráfico.

Na verdade criei um nome onde adicionei uma formula desloc que não só altera a altura do range como tb varia as colunas.

Explicando o processo:
Na planilha de dados do gráfico, a cada 2 colunas tenho informação de legenda e valores de um gráfico diferente, algo como na imagem anexa (Planilha Dados). Eu seleciono o tipo do gráfico no combo e o desloc vai para as colunas de legenda e valores referentes a seleção.

Nome: RangeGraficoLegenda
Formula: =DESLOC(Tabela2[[#Cabeçalhos];[Meses]];1;CORRESP(Dados!$G$2;Dados!$1:$1;0)-1;CONT.SE(Coluna;"<>");1)

Nome: RangeGraficoValores
Formula: =DESLOC(Tabela2[[#Cabeçalhos];[Meses]];1;CORRESP(Dados!$G$2;Dados!$1:$1;0);CONT.SE(Coluna;"<>");1)

Nome: Coluna
Formula: =DESLOC(Tabela2[[#Cabeçalhos];[Meses]];1;CORRESP(Dados!$G$2;Dados!$1:$1;0)-1;1000;1)

Repare na imagem que o combo esta relacionado com a célula G1 e que através de um procv eu busco qual o nome do gráfico na célula G2

O Nome Coluna apenas indica qual a coluna do gráfico selecionado para calcular a altura

O problema é que quando adiciono os nome "Grafico.xls!RangeGraficoValores" e "Grafico.xls!RangeGraficoLegenda" o grafico não se altera e quando volto para a seleção de dados da série do grafico percebo que os nomes somem e aparece um range normal. O curioso é que quando faço um teste e adiciono o "Grafico.xls!RangeGraficoValores" em ambos valores da série (valores e legenda) tudo funciona!

Como posso fazer com que meu grafico varie as informações?

Answer (score -1):

Gostaria que fizesse 2 coisas:

1. Postar a planilha para sentir melhor o que você quer; e
2. Diga se você tem ou não conhecimento em VBA do Excel.

Pelo o que "entendi", somente será possível com VBA, mas vou aguardar o acesso a sua planilha para confirmar.
Caso tenha "medo" de compartilhar as informações da empresa, altere os dados numéricos por outros, mas mantenha algum dado para poder testar.

At.

Comment: É mais indicado usar os comentários para este tipo de solicitação.

Comment: obrigado Jota. É possível substituir?

Comment: Também sou novato e o sistema aqui é um pouco diferente de outros fóruns. Acho que você pode incluir o texto do post acima como comentário e remover esta resposta. Deve aparecer para você a opção de remover do lado de editar.

Comment: Ainda não tenho 50 pontos de reputação para comentar na do criador. Assim que tiver faço a substituição. De toda forma obrigado.